# Using a single hashmap vs multiple variables

Tags: java

Lets say we have a class called CompHash with 30 different variables as follows:

```
   public class CompHash{
      private String abc1;
      private int sdf2;
             :
             :
      private float sgh30;
   }
```

and a similar class:

```
     public class CompHash{
         private HashMap diffVariables;
     }
```

In a situation where the number of variables that I will be needing varies from 1 to 30, which of the two would be better?

Comment: can you clarify more? how do u store variables to hashmap? it should be generic? your question is not clear.

Comment: diffVariables.put("abc1", new String("hello"));

Comment: What are those cryptically-named variables? Typically in an OO language your class names and attribute names have meaning and you don't end up in the situation you are describing. Do you just want to know what requires less storage and what runs faster?

Comment: and then how are you planning to use these variables within another class?

Comment: BTW don't use `new String("hello")`, `"hello"` is enough.

Comment: This is just an example, so I am not using variable names with any particular meaning. I wanted to know which one requires less space and better performance, wrt the situation I mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general you should **always** prefer strongly typed `CompHash` (the first one). Not only it is safer, but it will also be significantly faster.

If you have a requirement to store arbitrary number of variables, `HashMap` **might** be a good choice. But remember you are sacrificing type-safety without much gain - `HashMap` will probably still occupy more memory as opposed to a single object with lots of `null`s.

The only valid usage of `HashMap` is when you need to store arbitrary pairs (it is not clear whether variables/key names are constant in your case) of *key -> value*. But in this scenario I would recommend wrapping primitives with a class hierarchy having common ancestor and using `Visitor` pattern to avoid dangarous down-casts and ugly `instanceof`'s.

BTW what problem are you actually solving? The data structure you need seems a bit exotic...

Comment: OK. But what if, the number of variables required is too large, and only a small portion of it is used often?

Comment: I am just trying to find a better way of dealing with problems that arises when there are a lot of variables unused most of the time. Trying to keep the object size as small as needed.

Comment: he might need a Type safe heterogeneous container. :)

Comment: If you have a class with a large number of variables, and a lot of them are unused, you probably need to redesign your class.

Comment: If the key space is big but known and finite, most of the time I would go for fields. Of course if the key space is very large or not known prior runtime (e.g. *a class representing French names occurrences*), `Map` will be a better idea. A class with tens (not to mentions hundreds or thousands) of fields with only few not null is a disaster. Rule of thumb: if you hit 64K class size limit, go for `Map` ;-). Also think about your problem, my guess is that you should model the domain differently.

Comment: Harke, it sounds to me like you're trying to do premature optimization. Generally we just don't care about this unless we have to; a good design is better than trying to save space.

Comment: A class hierarchy + visitor pattern is by no means an obvious choice. Certainly a class of 30 member variables needs to be broken up, but composition is simpler, more readable and would probably suffice assuming there is a natural grouping among member variables.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider `List<T>` to store list of items, since you are not sure that there might be 1 to 30 variables. you can use a dynamic array, ie: list.

Storing an object to a list is not a very good idea, it will require casting when you want to use and if you dont know the type you stored, you will get a cast exception.

For example: if you want to store the name of the students who show up to class today, you can use a list. since you dont know how many students will show up, you are using arraylist cause of its dynamic nature.

```
List<String>
```

this would be your code.

I wouldnt recommend you to use a HashMap for store object fields that will store data, ie: properties.

Comment: U mean use List with type object?

Answer (score 0):

If your variable list of properties is a known entity, as in there will at most be X number of values and I know the type of value each of those will be, then certainly the first approach would make the most sense.  In that situation, as @Tomasz mentioned in his answer, is preferable.  You won't have to worry as much about type safety.

However, if your object has a set of properties and then needs to have a list of other things of varying types and a varying number, then a  HashMap might make sense.  There are some things to keep in mind.

First, specify types as well as possible.  For example:

```
HashMap<String,Object> myHash = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

If created in this way your hashmap keys will ALWAYS need to be a string.  If you're dealing with things that are named in a dynamic way, this can be a good way to go about it.  You'll notice second I'm only specifying Object.  Because of that, you can store any object type, and if you want to store primitives you'll need to do it with them as Integer, Double, String, ect., instead of int, double, string.

Then, the stressful part of structuring like this is that you'll need to cast and check types and be prepared to deal with it.  When you're pulling pieces of information back out you'll need to do something like this:

```
if myHash.get(key) instanceof Integer
     Integer myVal = (Integer) myHash.get(key);
else if myHash.get(key) instanceof Double
     Double myVal = (Double) myHash.get(key);
```

Then you'll need to check for type and cast as you pull values out  and then send them into new methods / logic based on not only the property name but the object type.  There are really useful things you can accomplish like this...but it can be difficult to do without painting yourself into an overly-complicated corner.  Especially when [Java's reflection api](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) can be used to get properties dynamically in a safer way (though not without its own headaches.)

Answer (score 0):

I like the first option with the strongly typed variables. BUT I will strongly consider grouping the 30 attributes into at least 4-5 classes if possible.